# Read/Reviewed Group Workflow Ending Too Soon

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, groups

I need to send out documents to particular groups. I'm using the Read/Reviewed workflow because we want to be able to track each person that opens the document and when, for auditing purposes. However, when I send it out to a group, it'll send the document to everyone in that group, but the first person to read/review the document ends the workflow for the whole group. I'm not able to track the individual members on the back end. I've tried both "one at a time" and "all at once" orders when setting up the workflow with the same result. How can I monitor the individual's access to the document without assigning the workflow to each individual person?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the "Start a Task Process"action in SharePoint designer workflow, please change the Completion Criteria to "Wait for all responses":

[image]

This option will make the workflow wait until all of the responses have been collected.It will return the outcome that received the most number of responses. In the event of a tie, the response that was received first will be returned.

If this is not feasible for you, please feel free to reply.